# Which Hash function laravel's Auth is using?

Tags: authentication, hash, laravel-4

I am trying to use Laravel's built in authentication, but it is not working. If I hash a password at the registration process, it does not match the hash in the login process, because  Laravel's auth generates a totally different hash than `Hash:make()`.

I made a test route and function, to make everything clear
(I tried to use the Auth::attempt() function with Hash::make() and without Hash::make() too, If I pass the Hashed password, it generates a totally different one, If I pass the raw password the Auth doesn't even bother to hash it):

```
Route::get('/test', function() {
    $email = rand(1, 1000) . "test@mail.com";
    $password = $email;
    $now = new DateTime();
    Felhasznalo::create(array(
        'teljesnev' => 'valami',
        'email' => $email,
        'jelszo' => Hash::make($password),
        'FelFelhasznaloiSzint_id' => 2,
        'created_at' => $now->getTimestamp(),
        'aktiv' => 1
    ));

    if (Auth::attempt(array(
                'email' => $email,
                'jelszo' => Hash:make($password)
            ))) {
        echo 'Working';
    } else {
        echo 'Not working';
    }
});
```

The first part generates this row to my mysql server:

```
39test@mail.com, $2y$10$gkzQ2BEuDWN05RQ/OyBH8u4aKRqdL5zSIthUO4BUyEKcscgzRwZzG, valami ....etc
```

I intentionally mistyped the password field's name to jelszo1 (means password1 in english), when attempting login, to get an sql error.

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'jelszo1' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `Felhasznalo` where `email` = 39test@mail.com and `jelszo1` = y$XAnnnGNKrOQOxBiX2BnEPOq86Y9mh5h./xwUlfCTPpzW.jzzt3YiO limit 1)
```

First part (in mysql):

```
$2y$10$gkzQ2BEuDWN05RQ/OyBH8u4aKRqdL5zSIthUO4BUyEKcscgzRwZzG
```

Second part (when attempting login):

```
y$XAnnnGNKrOQOxBiX2BnEPOq86Y9mh5h./xwUlfCTPpzW.jzzt3YiO
```

and the User model (named as Felhasznalo)

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class Felhasznalo extends \Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait,
        RemindableTrait;

    protected $fillable = [
        'id', 'email', 'jelszo', 'teljesnev', 'jelszoreset',
        'hash', 'aktiv', 'ban', 'FelFelhasznaloiSzint_id',
        'remember_token'
    ];
    protected $guarded = [
    ];
    protected $hidden = [
        'jelszo', 'jelszoreset', 'hash'
    ];
    protected $table = 'Felhasznalo';
    public $timestamps = true;
    protected $softDelete = true;

    //----------------------------
    //----------------------------
    // RELATIONSHIP FUNCTIONS
    //----------------------------
    //----------------------------

    /**
     * Get the unique identifier for the user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifier() {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    /**
     * Get the password for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword() {
        return $this->jelszo;
    }

    /**
     * Get the e-mail address where password reminders are sent.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getReminderEmail() {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function getRememberToken() {
        return $this->remember_token;
    }

    public function setRememberToken($value) {
        $this->remember_token = $value;
    }

    public function getRememberTokenName() {
        return 'remember_token';
    }

}
```

The auth config.:

```
'model' => 'Felhasznalo',
'table' => 'Felhasznalo',
```

SQL Error error when using raw password in attempt():

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'jelszo1' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `Felhasznalo` where `email` = 832test@mail.com and `jelszo1` = 832test@mail.com limit 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked the Auth code, your password column MUST be called `password`. You cannot use `jelszo`

Also - yourr login code is incorrect. You just do this:

```
if (Auth::attempt(array(
                'email' => $email,
                'password' => $password
            ))) {
        echo 'Working';
    } else {
        echo 'Not working';
    }
```

Auth::attempt() will do the hashing for you.

Comment: I edited my question, it does not. If I pass the raw password in, it does not hash it. Check the last part.

Comment: Yes it does. See the docs: http://laravel.com/docs/security#authenticating-users  - something else is going on with your code

Comment: I know It should, but it doesn't.

Comment: Aand it is true. Thank you. But why the hell is the getAuthPassword() function to the user model then. It is just stupid.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to Your question from the post's title (Which Hash function laravel's Auth is using?) can be found on [mnshankar.wordpress.com - Laravel Hash::make() explained](https://mnshankar.wordpress.com/2014/03/29/laravel-hash-make-explained/).

Here is the first sentence from the "**How?**" section of the linked blog post:

> Internally, Hash::make() encrypts using the **bcrypt** function and **Blowfish** algorithm.

Also, You can see on the [Laravel 5.4 docs - Hashing page](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/hashing#introduction) that they say:

> The Laravel Hash facade provides secure **Bcrypt** hashing for storing user passwords.